# How to check a certain checkbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox item like this:

```
 $("#userRoleDiv-"+note_id).append(" \n\
    <div><input name='userInput-"+note_id+"' type='checkbox' value='' id= '1' />Instructor</div>\n\
    <div><input name='userInput-"+note_id+"' type='checkbox' value='' id= '2' />Students</div>\n\
 ");
```

Now, I want to check checkboxes having id 1 and/or 2 but has the same name, as given in the code. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this too (It's clean). also don't need to use `\n` and notice `checked:checked`  (only one)

```
var instructor = $('<input/>', { 'name':'userInput-'+note_id, 'id':1, 'type':'checkbox', 'checked':'checked' });
var students = $('<input/>', { 'name':'userInputs-'+note_id, 'id':2, 'type':'checkbox' });

$("#userRoleDiv-"+note_id).append(
    $('<div/>', {'text':'Instructor'}).prepend(instructor),
    $('<div/>', {'text':'Students'}).prepend(students)
);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/JD8b9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `checked` attribute to the `<input>` element.

Also, you should wrap your inputs in `<label>` tags, so the label (Instructor and Student) will be clickable.

```
$("#userRoleDiv-"+note_id).append("
  <label><input name='userInput-"+note_id+"' type='checkbox' id='1' checked />Instructor</label>
  <label><input name='userInput-"+note_id+"' type='checkbox' id='2' />Students</label>
");
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a name:

```
var name = 'userInput-1';
```

Select the checkboxes like this:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[name=' + name + ']').filter('#1, #2');
```

Then check them:

```
checkboxes.each(function () { this.checked = true; });
```

Note that I haven't tested this; it may require modifications in order to work.